# HighchartsReact changing the legend symbol into Square

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I want to change the symbol of the legend from circle to square. is there a flag that I can add to the legend section to change it?
my legend section currenlty look like this:

```
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'left'
        },
```

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your area chart you can make the legend symbols square by removing their radius (rounding). For example ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.symbolRadius)):

```
legend: {
  symbolRadius: 0
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcugtk7s/).